# Get the average of some lines and the value of a single line in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table with 4 columns, like this:

```
ID - username - rating - solved
```

The DB is for a puzzle site. The `ID` is the # of the puzzle, the `username` field is for the user who solved it, and `solved` is a boolean if user has solved it. On the main page, I list the puzzles. I get the data of the puzzles (from an other table), the solved value for the puzzle for the logged in user, but when I try to get the average rating it averages the one value, the logged in user's rating for the puzzle, and ignores any other ratings for the puzzle. Can this be done in one single query, or only two, a separate one for the ratings? How?
Oh also, if there is no user logged in, meaning I don't have to get the `solved` value from the ratings table, the ratings are averaged and everything works fine.

EDIT: here is the code. $logged is if the user is logged in, so the top two queries work, the bottom two don't.

```
if ($logged) {
    $query_recent = "SELECT id, owner, title, hidden, x, y, solved, points, AVG(rating) AS average FROM `users`, `cwords` LEFT JOIN `ratings` ON `cwords`.`id`=`ratings`.`cw_id` AND `ratings`.`owner_id` = '$username' WHERE `cwords`.`public` = 1 AND `owner` = `username` GROUP BY `id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $from, 30";
    $query_top = "SELECT id, owner, title, hidden, x, y, solved, points, AVG(rating) AS average FROM `users`, `cwords`  LEFT JOIN `ratings` ON `cwords`.`id`=`ratings`.`cw_id` AND `ratings`.`owner_id` = '$username' WHERE `cwords`.`public` = 1 AND `owner` = `username` GROUP BY `id` ORDER BY average DESC LIMIT $from, 30";
  } else {
    $query_recent = "SELECT id, owner, title, hidden, x, y, points, AVG(rating) AS average FROM `users`, `cwords`  LEFT JOIN `ratings` ON `cwords`.`id`=`ratings`.`cw_id` WHERE `cwords`.`public` = 1 AND `owner` = `username` GROUP BY `id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $from, 30";
    $query_top = "SELECT id, owner, title, hidden, x, y, points, AVG(rating) AS average FROM `users`, `cwords` LEFT JOIN `ratings` ON `cwords`.`id`=`ratings`.`cw_id` WHERE `cwords`.`public` = 1 AND `owner` = `username` GROUP BY `id` ORDER BY average DESC LIMIT $from, 30";
  };
```

EDIT 2: I tried it with 2 queries, but if I try to select the `solved` value in a separate one I cant order it by the `AVG(rating)`, and I'm back to the original problem. Any help?

```
$query_top_solved = "SELECT id, solved FROM cwords LEFT JOIN ratings ON `cwords`.`id`=`ratings`.`cw_id` AND `ratings`.`owner_id` = '$username' WHERE `cwords`.`public` = 1 GROUP BY cw_id ORDER BY AVG(rating) DESC LIMIT $from, 30";
```

This orders it by the currently logged in user's rating, the single one.

Comment: post the queries you've tried, some sample data, and the results/expected results

Answer (score 1):

You'd need two separate queries. One to fetch the user's score, and one to fetch the overall average score.

```
SELECT rating, solved
FROM ...
WHERE username=$userID AND ID=$puzzleID
```

and

```
SELECT AVG(rating), AVG(solved)
FROM ...
WHERE ID=$puzzleID
```

Comment: and how do I repeat these in a `while` loop, so that the values go to the right puzzles?